# Remove Automatic Indent on Chapter Title

Tags: chapters

I am creating the format for my document and trying to set up the chapter/section/subsection etc.

When using the \chapter command the title is automatically indented. How do I make the chapter title move to the left of the page?

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article} 

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 

\begin{document}

\chapter{\Large \bf CHAPTER 1: INTRODUCTION}

\section{}
\subsection{First Section}

\end{document}
```

I would Like it to say "CHAPTER1: INTRODUCTION" on the left of the page, and below that say "1.1 First Section".

Comment: This is heavily dependent on the package you may use to influence the formatting of your chapters, or even the document class. Please provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the current problem.

Comment: @Werner

I am new to Latex and this forum. I have simplified my code to a MWE. What is the best way to post it for the commumity to see?

Comment: @RyanG -- add your code to the edit window, then highlight it by running your mouse over it, and then click on the `{}` icon above the edit window.  an alternative method is to insert 4 spaces at the beginning of each line, but it's really much easier to mark the whole insert at once.

Comment: What's the point if an empty `\maketitle`?

Comment: @Bernard Sorry, I have edited it to a simpler version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`article` doesn't have a `\chapter` command, so what's happening is that
this text is being treated as a new paragraph.

really, you're not using the `article` markup at all.  since putting in
null `\section` won't do any harm, i'm just going to suggest that you enter
your title as

```
\noindent{\Large \bfseries CHAPTER 1: INTRODUCTION}
```

oh, and `\maketitle` doesn't do anything here without a title.

someone else will no doubt suggest that you use a package to modify
the heading formats.  (i'm a bit of a renegade, and don't usually use
packages for that sort of modification, so i don't know the package
facilities without looking them up.  and my method for making such
changes is too arcane to spring on someone with little experience.)

what i *do* recommend, however, is that you read up on the `report` class.
that has `\chapter` and the rest of the structural headings defined, so
it fits more closely what you seem to have in mind here.  and *then* look
into other packages for adapting the format of the headings.

Comment: This makes much more sense, thank you! I am writing a thesis and the report class seems much more appropriate.

Comment: I'd suggest `book` or `memoir`, rather than `report`.

Comment: @RyanG -- egreg is correct here.  possibly easier to start drafting text with `book`, but when you want to polish your presentation, and have a bit more experience with latex, `memoir` has many more, and easier to use, facilities for reshaping the appearance.  i think i'm correct in saying that the major divisioning commands in `memoir` match those of `book` (or `report`), so migration shouldn't be too much of a headache.

Comment: @barbarabeeton
great thanks, I will start learning the different classes